# Ошибка с RecyclerView, не могу найти ее решение

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Вылезает следующая ошибка, и как правильно ее поправить я не могу сообразить. Подскажите, я уверен что с этим много кто сталкивается.

**Upd.** Ошибка возникает тогда, когда я сделал скрол, у меня подзагрузились элементы, далее я перешел на другой экран, потом возвращаюсь на экран в список, который был проскролен и вот такая вылезает ошибка:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionNewCatalogActivitySection3Adapter2ViewHolder{3bb30c4 position=13 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{176b385 VFED..... .F...... 0,250-1080,2081 #7f0a016f app:id/rv_numbers}, adapter:com.almazholding.myapplication.newCatalogActivitySection3.NewCatalogActivitySection3Adapter2@862f96b, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager@de4fcc8, context:com.almazholding.myapplication.newCatalogActivitySection3.NewCatalogActivitySection3@899825e
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:6072)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6255)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:288)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:345)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:361)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:368)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:399)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Код адаптера такой:

```
public class NewCatalogActivitySection3Adapter2 extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<NewCatalogActivitySection3Adapter2.NewCatalogActivitySection3Adapter2ViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<RESPONSE> items;
    Context context;
    BottomNavigationView navigation;

    public NewCatalogActivitySection3Adapter2(ArrayList<RESPONSE> items, Context context, BottomNavigationView navigation) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
        this.navigation = navigation;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewCatalogActivitySection3Adapter2ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_item, parent, false);
        return new NewCatalogActivitySection3Adapter2.NewCatalogActivitySection3Adapter2ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewCatalogActivitySection3Adapter2ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(items != null) return items.size();
        else return 0;
    }

    class NewCatalogActivitySection3Adapter2ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {

        private final LinearLayout price_block;
        private final LinearLayout price_block_ms;
        private final TextView nameTextView;
        private final TextView minPriceTextView;
        private final TextView bonusPrice;
        private final TextView hints;
        private final TextView movie_item_favorites;
        private final ImageView mobilePictureImageView;
        private final ArrayList<Integer> favoriteIdList;

        final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        public NewCatalogActivitySection3Adapter2ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_item_name);
            minPriceTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_item_min_price);
            bonusPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_item_bonus_price);
            hints = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_item_hints);
            mobilePictureImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_item_mobile_picture);
            movie_item_favorites = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_item_favorites);

            price_block = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_block);
            price_block_ms = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_block_ms);

            DBHelper dbHelper;
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
            SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

            String query = "SELECT * FROM favorites";
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
            favoriteIdList = new ArrayList<>();
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                favoriteIdList.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        void bind(RESPONSE item) {
            nameTextView.setText(item.getNAME());
            //minPriceTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%,d", movie.getPricePrice()) + "");

            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();
            DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
            symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');              //явно задаем символ разделителя тысяч
            formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

            minPriceTextView.setText(formatter.format(item.getPRICE().getPRICE()));
            bonusPrice.setText(formatter.format(item.getPRICE().getBASE()) + " Р");

            if(item.getPRICE().getPRICE() > 999999 || item.getPRICE().getBASE() > 999999){
                price_block.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                layoutParams.setMarginStart(0);

                price_block_ms.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }

            if(favoriteIdList.contains(item.getID())) {
                if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    movie_item_favorites.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_action_heart));
                } else {
                    movie_item_favorites.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_action_heart));
                }
            }

            movie_item_favorites.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                DBHelper dbHelper;
                dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

                Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favorites where id=" + item.getID(), null);

                if(cursor2.getCount() > 0) {
                    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM favorites where id=" + item.getID() + ";");

                    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        movie_item_favorites.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_action_heart_empty) );
                    } else {
                        movie_item_favorites.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_action_heart_empty));
                    }
                } else {
                    cv.put("name", item.getNAME());
                    cv.put("urlPict", item.getMOBILEPICTURE());
                    cv.put("id", item.getID());
                    cv.put("price", item.getPRICE().getPRICE());
                    cv.put("priceOld", item.getPRICE().getBASE());
                    cv.put("quantity", 1);
                    cv.put("article", item.getCODE());
                    cv.put("size", "");
                    cv.put("detail_page_url", item.getDETAILPAGEURL());

                    db.insert("favorites", null, cv);

                    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        movie_item_favorites.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_action_heart) );
                    } else {
                        movie_item_favorites.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_action_heart));
                    }
                }

                final SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

                String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM favorites;";
                Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

//                    TODO Мне не нравится это
                int menuItemId = navigation.getMenu().getItem(2).getItemId();
                BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = navigation.getOrCreateBadge(menuItemId);


                String queryCart = "SELECT count(*) FROM cart;";
                Cursor cursorCart = database.rawQuery(queryCart, null);
                cursorCart.moveToFirst();

                int menuItemIdCart = navigation.getMenu().getItem(3).getItemId();
                BadgeDrawable badgeDrawableCart = navigation.getOrCreateBadge(menuItemIdCart);

                if (cursorCart.getInt(0) > 0) {
                    badgeDrawableCart.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8C1818"));
                    badgeDrawableCart.setNumber(cursorCart.getInt(0));
                    badgeDrawableCart.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    badgeDrawableCart.setVisible(false);
                }

                if (cursor.getInt(0) > 0) {
                    badgeDrawable.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8C1818"));
                    badgeDrawable.setNumber(cursor.getInt(0));
                    badgeDrawable.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    badgeDrawable.setVisible(false);
                }

                cursor.close();
                dbHelper.close();

            });

            if(!item.getHINTS().equals("null")) {
                hints.setText(item.getHINTS());
            } else {
                hints.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            Picasso
                    .get()
                    .load(item.getMOBILEPICTURE())
                    .resize(390, 390)
                    .centerInside()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.preloader)
                    .error(R.drawable.preloader)
                    .into(mobilePictureImageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                RESPONSE item = items.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CatalogElementActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("elementPageURL", item.getDETAILPAGEURL());

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(context, "Произошла ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не очень хорошая практика иметь внутри RecyclerView.Adapter списки которые могут быть null.

Попробуйте ваш список айтемов объявить изначально, как пустой список. А дальше просто обновляйте его.

```
private final ArrayList<RESPONSE> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

Вот здесь тогда вам ну нужен будет никакой `if`:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
```

Я думаю ваша проблема в том, что вы где-то передаете (или еще не успеваете передать нормальный список) `null` и из-за этого ваш `VH` обращается к несуществующему элементу

Comment: Я конечно может быть плохо java знаю, но как я буду обновлять final коллекцию... Если я ее объявляю как final, то даже конструктор не могу объявить, который обязателен при создании адаптера.

Comment: Ну есть 2 пути. 1ый - не объявлять как final - в этом нет ничего критичного. Главное чтоб она наружу не торчала. Второй - никто не отменял методов `addAll()` и `clear()`

Comment: Сергей, я написал апдейт к ошибке, описал как именно она у меня возникает.

Upd. Ошибка возникает тогда, когда я сделал скрол, у меня подзагрузились элементы, далее я перешел на другой экран, потом возвращаюсь на экран в список, который был проскролен и вот такая вылазит ошибка:

Comment: Вы выложили огромный адаптер которых ходит в базу данных, чего делать не должен. Понять что у вас не работает очень трудно. Очевидно, что вы где-то пробует обратиться к элементу списка которого не существует. Но я бы вообще рекомендовал вам переписать адаптер с нуля. Вынести из него все запросы в БД. Адаптер не должен ничего знать о таких вещах, он должен уметь только рисовать списк. Тогда вероятнее всего ваша проблема решиться либо сама в процессе переписывания либо вам намного проще будет ее найти.